# General number formatting (#,00) in mvc asp.net and switching between formats

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formatting, numbers

My main problem is that i need to be able to have asp.mvc accept the Danish number format (meaning a dot every thousand and a comma seperator). Since i am working on a larger system, I need a more in-depth solution.

The formating problem includes the fact that I need to beable to solve the errorhandling aswell, which does not accept the 0,00 as a number. best case, the solution still maintains the possibility to calculate with the numbers without having to format them each time.

As another point, I need to beable to switch between the English format, meaning (0.00) and the Danish (0,00).

TL;DR

Solve the problem of using a diffrent formatting in mvc asp.net from (en 0.00) to (da 0,00), including errorhandling, still allowing for calculations in jquery or javascript, and the posibility to switch back to the english format (0.00).

What would be the best way to go about this?

---

Edit: Solved most of it!

To get the View (Jquery validate) to accept comma as a seperator I've inserted "One regexp" from this: http://mfranc.com/javascript/jquery-valdiator-modyfing-decimal-separator/

Adding the custom model binding, provided by @chrispratt solved the problem of the controller receiving the number in the right format.

On top of this I've added code to modify any number entered into an input field into the right format.
Also all numbers and their display formats are checked before being shown. (since some doubles display without ,00)

I think that should be it, now all that remains is to devise some method of switching between languages and formats, which I should beable to manage.

Thanks for the help!

---

Any help is apprichiated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This largely handled by adding support for globalization. The only issue you're going to run into is that the default model binder *only* accepts English-formatted decimal values. However, you can create a custom model binder to make use of globalization. Check out http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/

Comment: In your view in httpattributes, put Value=MyMethodConverter(Model.MyField)  where MyMethodConverter is a call in the c# code where you can decide on English vs Danish return value.

Comment: @kblau 
I have not seen anything like that before, is that common practise? 
I suppose you mean something like this: 

" @Html.EditorFor(model => model.foo, new { htmlAttributes = new {Value=@service.MyMethodConverter(@Model.foo) }", correct?

Could you link me an article or simular about this?
I am a bit confused about how this would work, I'll do some testing.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks a lot! Updated my answer if you are interested about the other aspects of the question. Again thanks!